# Enabling Synonyms in Django Haystack with Elasticsearch Backend

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I am having issues using a synonym filter within hackstack using an Elasticsearch custom backend.

All I am trying to do at this point is to create one synonym for testing purposes. I would like to add a synonym pairing for the word 'tricklenutz' to the word 'lipstick'.

I am using the following custom haystack backend:

```
from django.conf import settings
from haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend import (ElasticsearchSearchBackend,
    ElasticsearchSearchEngine)

class SiteElasticBackend(ElasticsearchSearchBackend):

    def __init__(self, connection_alias, **connection_options):
        super(SiteElasticBackend, self).__init__(
                                connection_alias, **connection_options)
        MY_SETTINGS = {
            'settings': {
                "analysis": {
                    "analyzer": {
                        "synonym_analyzer": {
                            "type": "custom",
                            "tokenizer": "lowercase",
                            "filter": ["synonym"]
                        },
                        "ngram_analyzer": {
                            "type": "custom",
                            "tokenizer": "lowercase",
                            "filter": ["haystack_ngram", "synonym"]
                        },
                        "edgengram_analyzer": {
                            "type": "custom",
                            "tokenizer": "lowercase",
                            "filter": ["haystack_edgengram", "synonym"]
                        }
                    },
                    "tokenizer": {
                        "haystack_ngram_tokenizer": {
                            "type": "nGram",
                            "min_gram": 3,
                            "max_gram": 15,
                        },
                        "haystack_edgengram_tokenizer": {
                            "type": "edgeNGram",
                            "min_gram": 2,
                            "max_gram": 15,
                            "side": "front"
                        }
                    },
                    "filter": {
                        "synonym": {
                            "type": "synonym",
                            "synonyms": [
                                "tricklenutz, lipstick"
                            ]
                        },
                        "haystack_ngram": {
                            "type": "nGram",
                            "min_gram": 3,
                            "max_gram": 15
                        },
                        "haystack_edgengram": {
                            "type": "edgeNGram",
                            "min_gram": 5,
                            "max_gram": 15
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        setattr(self, 'DEFAULT_SETTINGS', MY_SETTINGS)


class ConfigurableElasticSearchEngine(ElasticsearchSearchEngine):
    backend = SiteElasticBackend
```

As you can see, I am just trying to create a synonym for 'lipstick' to 'tricklenutz' (a word that does not show up in any searches).

I have the following entry in my `settings.py` file:

`HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'search.backends.site_elasticsearch_backend.ConfigurableElasticSearchEngine',
        'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/',
        'INDEX_NAME': 'sitename'
    },
}`

Here is my search_index.py for a `Brand`:

```
class BrandIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    ngram_text = indexes.EdgeNgramField()
    name = indexes.NgramField(model_attr='name')
    brand_name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='name')
    created_date = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='created_date')

    def get_model(self):
        return Brand

    def prepare(self, obj):
            """Add the content of text field from final prepared data into ngram_text field
            """
            prepared_data = super(BrandIndex, self).prepare(obj)
            prepared_data['ngram_text'] = prepared_data['text']
            return prepared_data

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return Brand.objects.filter(created_date__lte=datetime.datetime.now())
```

And here is the view portion for the search:

```
class BrandListSearchResults(ListSearchResultsViewMixin, BrandListBase):
    template_name = 'search/brand/search.html'
    page_template = 'search/brand/page.html'
    paginate_by = 50
    paginate_by_first = 50

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.get_sqs().filter(text=self.search_term)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(BrandListSearchResults, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        meta = Meta(
            title='All brands matching the search term %s' % self.search_term,
            description='Brand search results for %s' % self.search_term
        )
        data['meta'] = meta
        data['paginate_by'] = self.paginate_by
        data['paginate_by_first'] = self.paginate_by_first
        data['size_list'] = ["90","110","185"]
        return data
```

I have re-run my indexing but the synonym does not appear to be working.

Is there a way that I can query Elasticsearch to see if the synonyms actually exist? The haystack manage command is not very verbose about what it is doing with custom filters, etc.

**Update**

I have been able to query my settings directly from elasticsearch and I see that the synonyms are there:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/sitename/_settings?pretty'
{
  "sitename" : {
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "creation_date" : "1427470212556",
        "uuid" : "6eznekoORQKqwswTq1G24w",
        "analysis" : {
          "analyzer" : {
            "synonym_analyzer" : {
              "type" : "custom",
              "filter" : [ "synonym" ],
              "tokenizer" : "lowercase"
            },
            "ngram_analyzer" : {
              "type" : "custom",
              "filter" : [ "haystack_ngram", "synonym" ],
              "tokenizer" : "lowercase"
            },
            "edgengram_analyzer" : {
              "type" : "custom",
              "filter" : [ "haystack_edgengram", "synonym" ],
              "tokenizer" : "lowercase"
            }
          },
          "filter" : {
            "haystack_ngram" : {
              "type" : "nGram",
              "min_gram" : "3",
              "max_gram" : "15"
            },
            "haystack_edgengram" : {
              "type" : "edgeNGram",
              "min_gram" : "5",
              "max_gram" : "15"
            },
            "synonym" : {
              "type" : "synonym",
              "synonyms" : [ "tricklenutz, lipstick" ]
            }
          },
          "tokenizer" : {
            "haystack_edgengram_tokenizer" : {
              "max_gram" : "15",
              "min_gram" : "2",
              "type" : "edgeNGram",
              "side" : "front"
            },
            "haystack_ngram_tokenizer" : {
              "type" : "nGram",
              "min_gram" : "3",
              "max_gram" : "15"
            }
          }
        },
        "number_of_replicas" : "1",
        "number_of_shards" : "5",
        "version" : {
          "created" : "1040399"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I notice is that you have your `synonym_analyzer` analyzer configured but unused! You need to either set the default analyzer or do this on a field-by-field basis (which requires additional changes in your custom backend as well as extended field classes; [here's an example](https://github.com/bennylope/elasticstack/blob/master/elasticstack/backends.py#L22)).

I've encountered similar frustration about understanding how documents are actually handled from Django to ElasticSearch. You can use a combination of just hitting ElasticSearch's HTTP API and some additional introspection via Haystack. I wrote a command in the linked `elasticstack` package called [`show_mapping`](https://github.com/bennylope/elasticstack/blob/master/elasticstack/management/commands/show_mapping.py) which shows the JSON used to create your mapping. This way you can at least see whether your fields are configured to use the analyzers you've set up.

*Short disclaimer - I have not kept up with the most recent changes in Haystack (after 2.0 or 2.1) so it's possible some of these suggestions themselves need updating.*

Comment: Thank you very much bennylope I will make these changes and let you know how it goes.